# Android Big view for multiline notifications for OS < 4.1

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I have gone through the documentation for generating multi-line **android notifications** using the android **Big view** documentation given [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

The problem is that, this feature is supported for `OS 4.1+`. I wish to obtain a consistent notification content across all the platforms, i.e. multi line notifications for OS <4.1 . Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just use a detail layout for notification for Android < 4.1. So all users get almost the same experience. I don't think there's a way to achieve new features on outdated Android versions.

Comment: :( so no solution exists. So do you use a custom layout for notifications?